# Fit image without defined parent heights

Tags: html, css, image-resizing

The website I was tasked with making has a watermark, which for my own sanity I coded as a separate object rather than a background. (For the record, this problem persists even when changed to a background of each and every parent element.) I've recently had to add a scrollable page to the site, which immediately broke everything. I had to set the height of the html and body elements to auto so they would capture the child elements, but now the watermark is stuck covering whatever percentage of the page my monitor can display at one time. Set to auto, the image maxes out and still doesn't stretch all the way to the bottom. Annoyingly the problem is only visible if the screen is wider than it is tall.

Here's the HTML affecting the image:

```
<html>
<body>

<section>
     <img src="Buttons/HomeWatermark3.png">
</section>

</body>
</html>
```

And the CSS:

```
html { 
    width: 100%;
    height: auto; }

html body {
    margin:0;
    padding: 0; }

body {
    background-color: #003678;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%; }

/* --------------------- Watermark ------------------- */
section img {
    z-index: -20;
    opacity: 0.1;
    position: absolute;
    right:0;
    height: 100%;
    width: auto;}
```

How the heck can I make the image cooperate with the new layout?

Update: I made the image twice as large and still had the same issue on auto, so I guess it's not maxing out.

Edit: I forgot to mention that if the watermark's height is set to auto it overflows on all the non-scrolly pages, which kinda sucks.

Edit again: here's more of my code in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ShiningSnow/od0h93Ly/5/), showing the image limit. Overflow is on purpose, I just need the image to match it.

Comment: Could we see this in action?

Comment: Try removing some CSS I was able to make it work with this: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tvsoxney/2/)

Comment: Ok, I try the jsfiddle, And what is your expectation?

Comment: There's a ton of code and it calls some stuff from an intranet so I can't really quickly create the same issue, but I can upload a picture later. My goal is to make the watermark fill the body element, since the body element now automatically covers the whole page.

Comment: I dropped in a very ugly version of my grid to the jsfiddle and it immediately overflowed. [Here's the link](https://jsfiddle.net/ShiningSnow/od0h93Ly/), which shows the issue. I added padding to the top to simulate the header and nav bar.  I want it to overflow, I just also want the image to overflow an equal amount.

Answer (score 0):

Add `position:relative;` to the body.

https://jsfiddle.net/xka8Lq30/